# Accessing value from mongodb with Scala

Tags: json, mongodb, scala

After executing a MongoDB query my result is of type : `res = Seq[Document]`

To access the `BsonString` I use : `res (0).get("n"))`

Which returns :

```
Some(BsonString{value='value'})
```

How can I access the value `value` from the BsonString as a String ?

Accessing the value of `Some(BsonString{value='value'})` returns `BsonString{value='value'}` do I need to convert `BsonString{value='value'}` to a Scala object using a library (for example Jackson) and then access the value  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using the mongo scala driver (and not ReactiveMongo).

In that case, the returned `BsonString` is a java object; [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.0/scaladoc/#org.mongodb.scala.bson.package@BsonString=org.bson.BsonString) is the scaladoc that points to the javadoc.

And you can access the value via the `getValue` method.

As you are getting back `Option` objects, I would recommend to use proper for comprehension to avoid runtime exceptions; something like:

```
val optionalResult = for {
  doc <- res.headOption
  element <- doc.get[BsonString]("n")
} yield (element.getValue)
```

`optionalResult` will be of type `Option[String]`. 
You can then check if you have a value and use it; via map, flatMap, foreach or even `if (optionalResult.isDefined)`.

Comment: thanks, you got me on right track, I needed to modify your for comprehension to :  val optionalResult = for {
  doc <- res.headOption
  element <- doc.get("n")
} yield (element.asString.getValue)

Comment: I edited the answer to explicitly ask for a `BsonString`. The `asString` method is defined on the java class and throws an exception if it's not a `BsonString`. It's better to use the mechanism defined in the scala `Document` class which returns you `None` if the value is not a `BsonString`